# How can I evaluate more accurate energy eigenvalues from Schrodinger equation using shooting method?

Tags: python, precision, numerical-methods, scientific-computing, numerical-analysis

I am trying to use "shooting method" for solving Schrodinger's equation for a reasonably arbitrary potential in 1D. But the eigenvalues so evaluated in the case of potentials which do not have hard boundaries(where potential becomes infinite) are not much accurate compared to analytical results.

I thought that the problem could be solved,by making the spatial grid finer,but changing the spatial grid does not practically have any effect on the eigenvalues.I am not making the energy-grid finer,because the job of fining down to the correct eigenvalue is tackled by bisection method from scipy,and the wavefunction is evaluated by solving the concerned ivp by odeint from scipy-these functions are accurate enough.
Finally,changing the 2nd boundary to make the wavefunction die out at deeper part of classically forbidden region also did not bring a practical improvement in the eigenvalue(Changes found only in 9th or 10th place of decimal but made wavefunctions of lower energy state divergent at endpoints to make things worse).

I cannot find what to modify to obtain more accurate eigenvalues.Boundary condition or stepsize? Did my implementation go wrong,or is it due to rounding errors or other "Python things"?

Example--Morse potential(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_potential)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint,simps
from scipy.optimize import bisect
from math import e,floor

xe,lam=1.0,6.0 # parameters for potential
def V(x):return (lam**2)*(e**(-2*(x-xe))-2*(e**-(x-xe))) # morse potential definition

bound1,bound2,bval1,bval2=0,xe+15,0,0 # Bval,Bval2=wavefunction values at x=bound1,bound2
X=np.linspace(bound1,bound2,1000) # region of integration
Erange=np.geomspace(-(lam**2),-0.0001,100) # region of Energy level searching

def func(y,x): # utility function for returning RHS of the differential equation
    psi,phi=y # psi=eigenfunction,phi=spatial derivative of psi
    return np.array([phi,-(E-V(x))*psi])

def ivp(f,initial1,initial2,X): # solves an ivp with odeint
    y0=np.array([initial1,initial2])
    return odeint(f,y0,X)[:,0]

def psiboundval(E1):  # finds out value of eigenfunction at bound2 for energy E1,by solving ivp
    global E;E=E1
    S=ivp(func,bval1,E1,X)
    return S[(len(S))-1]-bval2

def shoot(Erange): # finds out accurate eigenvalues from approximate ones in Erange by bisect
    global E
    Y=np.array([psiboundval(E) for E in Erange])
    eigval=np.array([bisect(psiboundval,Erange[i],Erange[i+1]) for i in np.where(np.diff(np.signbit(Y)))[0]])
    return eigval

print "Numerical results:",shoot(Erange)
print "Analytical results:",[-(lam-n-0.5)**2 for n in range(0,int(floor(lam-0.5)+1))]
```

Output

```
>>> Numerical results: [-30.24833663 -20.24320174 -12.23610971  -6.23177902  -2.23431356
  -0.24381032]
Analytical results: [-30.25, -20.25, -12.25, -6.25, -2.25, -0.25]
```

For higher energy states,accuracy is seen to decrease.It is desirable that accuracy is of atleast upto 4th decimal place(if not more), for all states.